# How to insert menu-item into YouTube context-item

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to know how i can insert `menu-item` into YouTube `context-item` using `Google chrome extension`.
I searched for that a lot and i found similar question but no any persuasive answer.

I need the solution very much.

Comment: What is a "YouTube context-item"?

Comment: The Menu list which display when i press on right mouse button on video

Answer (score 0):

The chrome extension API includes a [Context Menu](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) feature, but since the YouTube player uses Flash, there is a completely separate context menu that Chrome does not have direct control over.

So it is not possible to customize the context menu with the Chrome API. However, you may be able to get by with a (somewhat hacky) solution, such as covering the video with a transparent HTML DOM element. The DOM element should trigger Chrome's context menu instead of the Flash context menu.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but if i do your solution, the default YouTube context-menu will be disable, In other word, i need the YouTube context-menu to display by the same mouse click, but in your way the YouTube context menu will disable and i need both to display.